# How to keep created elements on the web page after the page reload using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a web page for my little brother.It's about a user interactive page for adding comments by the users.I am having trouble, after created the user comments with a for.Each function, in keeping those created comments on the web page after the page refresh.I know that i have to use "local.storage" function but i didn't find any solution yet :'-(Can any good person help me please??Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Comments</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nmComments.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <a class="logo" href="#">
      <p>Comments page</p>
    </a>
    <button class="button--menu">
      <ion-icon class="menu--icon" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="main">
      <form class="comment--form" action="#" id="form">
        <h1 class="interact">Interact with us!<br>Leave your comment here</h1>

        <div>
          <label for="comment--text">Your comment:</label><br>
          <textarea class="comment--box" type="text" required id="textarea" placeholder="Add your comment"
            maxlength="150"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="form--button" id="submit">Paste it</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <h2 class="comments--h2">Comments</h2>
    <div id="comment--area" class="comment--area">
      <!-- <div class="client--box">
        <div id="name-box"></div>
      <div id="comment-box">
        </div>
        <button id="clear" class="hidden">
          &#128591;</button>
      </div> -->
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </footer>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

  <script language="Javascript">
const field = document.getElementById('textarea');

const submit = document.getElementById('submit');

const createComments = document.getElementById('comment--area');

const comments_arr = [];


submit.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const content = field.value;
    if(content.length > 0){ // if there is content add the comment to the array
    
      comments_arr.push(content);

      // re-generate the comment html list

      display_comments();
      
      // reset the textArea and arrey contents
      comments_arr.length = 0;
      field.value = '';
      
    }
}

const display_comments = ()=> {
  let box = document.createElement('textarea');
  box.classList.add('comment--box');
  createComments.append(box);
  let list = '';
   comments_arr.forEach(comment =>  {
    list +=  comment;
  })

  box.append(list);
  box.innerHTML = list;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't you insert those comments in the database if you wish to keep them?

Comment: thank you Chris but i am a noob of web development and i dunno how to create a database :'(

Comment: If you want the comments to be seen by anybody else localStorage is not the answer, you must persist the data on the server for it to be accessible by any other visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

Normally is better if you used a database but since you don't know how to, you can do it like this with the help of `localStorage`

This line will tell your code that your initial arrays value is either whatever was store in localstorage or an empty array if nothing was stored yet

```
let comments_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("comments")) || [];
```

so whenever you press the button you will `push` a new value to your array and save the updated array to your storage with this:

```
comments_arr.push(field.value);//push value to array

window.localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(comments_arr));//save to storage
```

Finally when you need to show all comments just loop thru your array and create a textarea for each comment you have then proceed to append like you were doing to your `createComments` element.

This is how the final code will look:

```js
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const createComments = document.getElementById('comment--area');
let comments_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("comments")) || [];
display_comments();
//window.localStorage.clear(comments_arr);

submit.onclick = function(event) {
  let field = document.getElementById('textarea');
  event.preventDefault();
  if (field.value.length > 0) { // if there is content add the comment to the array
    comments_arr.push(field.value);
    window.localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(comments_arr));
    // re-generate the comment html list
    display_comments();
    field.value = '';
  }
}

function display_comments() {
  let box;
  createComments.innerHTML = ''; //reset DOM
  for (let i = 0; i < comments_arr.length; i++) {
    box = document.createElement('textarea');
    box.classList.add('comment--box');
    box.value = comments_arr[i];
    createComments.append(box);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Comments</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nmComments.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <a class="logo" href="#">
      <p>Comments page</p>
    </a>
    <button class="button--menu">
      <ion-icon class="menu--icon" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="main">
      <form class="comment--form" action="#" id="form">
        <h1 class="interact">Interact with us!<br>Leave your comment here</h1>

        <div>
          <label for="comment--text">Your comment:</label><br>
          <textarea class="comment--box" type="text" required id="textarea" placeholder="Add your comment" maxlength="150"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="form--button" id="submit">Paste it</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <h2 class="comments--h2">Comments</h2>
    <div id="comment--area" class="comment--area">
      <!-- <div class="client--box">
        <div id="name-box"></div>
      <div id="comment-box">
        </div>
        <button id="clear" class="hidden">
          &#128591;</button>
      </div> -->
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </footer>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

  <script language="Javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are just going to ignore the fact that these comments will only ever live on the machine of the user that created them?

Comment: I did told him that he needed to use a database for that, but since he didn't know how to use a `localStorage` either, might as well show him anyway. Using a database is a whole other subject that I won't cover on my answer